# The structure of a finitely generated abelian group and its endomorphism ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups, noncommutative-algebra

This is a question from our past exams. I worked it out. Would anyone kind enough to check the correctness? Thanks! (It occurred several times that I somehow skipped crucial steps or overlooked something in algebra problems.)

Let $A$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ spanned by $(2,2,4),(1,3,-2),(1,-1,6)$. Let $H=\mathbb{Z}^3/A$ and $R=\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(H)$. Determine whether $R$ is Artinian or Noetherian (as a $\mathbb{Z}-$module).

**My attempts**

*The structure of $H$*

Note that $(1,3,-2)+(1,-1,6)=(2,2,4)$, we have $A=\langle(1,3,-2),(1,-1,6)\rangle=\langle(1,3,-2),(0,-4,8)\rangle.$
On the other hand,
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& -1\\
1 & 3 & -2\\
0 & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=1.$$
In the new set of generators $(0,0,-1),(1,3,-2),(0,-1,2)$, $\mathbb{Z}^3$ remains itself and $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus 4\mathbb{Z}.$ Thus, $H=\mathbb{Z}^3/A\simeq \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.$

The essential idea here is to work out the Smith normal form of

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 &4\\
1 &3 & -2\\
1 & -1 & 6
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
& 4\\
& & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

*The structure of $R$ as a ring*

Write elements in $H$ as $\begin{pmatrix}
a \\ [b]
\end{pmatrix},$ the elements in $R$ can be viewed as $2\times 2$ matrices:
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\
[b_1] & [b_2]
\end{pmatrix}

Sadly $R$ is not commutative:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 0\\
[b_1] & [b_2]
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a_2 & 0\\
[c_1] & [c_2]
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1a_2 & 0\\
[a_2b_1+b_2c_1] & [b_2c_2]
\end{pmatrix}$$

*The structure of $R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}-$module*

Note that $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb Z)=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$, $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=0.$ Hence $R=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.$

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb Z$ are Noetherian modules, the so does their direct product $R$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Z}\supset2\mathbb{Z}\supset2^2\mathbb{Z}\supset\cdots$ is a infinite strictly descending sequence of submodules. Hence $R$ is not Artinian.

Many thanks to @Maty and @user26857.

Comment: Well, the question asks you nothing about $R$, but anyway.. I think the product decomposition you wrote for $R$ is not a ring decomposition, only a $\mathbb{Z}$-module decomposition.

Comment: Edited. And more confusion emerges.

Comment: As you noticed, $R$ is isomorphic to the matrix ring $\left(\begin{array}{cc}\mathbb Z & \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z \\ 0 &\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\end{array}\right)$. Since $\mathbb Z$ is not artinian, $R$ is not artinian, too.

Comment: @user26857 Now that $R$ is not a commutative ring, so probably the question intends to ask whether $R$ is artinian (noetherian) as a module. Hopefully this kind of ambiguity will never occur in the Qual.

Comment: $R$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$, so is Noetherian as a module and as a ring. It is infinite, so is not Artinian as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. It has $\mathbb{Z}$ as an ideal, so it's not Artinian as a ring either.